# How to replace all underscore with dots

Tags: command-line

I want to replace all underscore from the first column of CSV file. It should do anything with the other column of csv file.

I only able to find this:
**sed 's/_/./g' file.txt**

But I want to replace all underscore with dot only in first column of text file.
How do I pass first column to sed command?

Thanks

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: What language do you want to use? Have you done any thinking for yourself? Have you attempted to use google at all?

Comment: I think excel is better than anything

Comment: There is sed command to do this...but do not find which can only replace underscore with dots from the first column.

Comment: Please update your question using the edit button to show us what you have tried in sed, and I will be more than happy to help. Edit: I would probably write a python script for this (I am partial towards python)

Comment: will this command will do this job:   cut -c 1 file.txt | sed 's/_/./g' file.txt

Comment: I'd suggest using `awk` or `perl` in preference to `sed` - they are more appropriate for structured (field based) text

Comment: That's a good start, but I think you would want to (the cut command at least) `cut -f1 -d '","` But as steeldriver said `awk` or `perl` would be better (or python :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed has no built-in notion of "columns", so rather than replacing characters globally (with the `g` substitution flag) you would need to replace them one at a time in a loop, breaking from the loop when there are no more characters to be replaced before the first delimiter. For example:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '/^[^,]*_[^,]*,/!b' -e 's/_/./;ta' file.csv
```

IMHO it would be easier to use a tool that natively understands *fields* - for example with Awk:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {gsub(/_/,".",$1); print}' file.csv
```

Note that *both* of these will break if your CSV file contains quoted delimiters - if that's the case, then you will need to step up to a tool that can parse CSV properly - such as Perl with the Text::CSV module.

Comment: Neither of these look like they break with quoted delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend awk over sed for this job:

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS}{gsub(/_/,".",$1);print}' yourfile.csv
```

-F is the field separator and here we set it to a comma. OFS=FS changes the output field separator to whatever you gave for -F so you retain the separator in the output result. $1 is the first column ($2 is the 2nd, etc.), so you can change it if you need to do something with other columns.